# Why do I have to specify types in tsconfig.json if type definitions are already in package.json

Tags: typescript

I have `"@types/gapi.client.gmail": "~1.0.3"` in `package.json`.

I also had this in `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "types": [
    "jest",
    "gapi",
    "gapi.auth2",
    "gapi.client.docs"
  ],
```

I can't recall why those statements are there.  But now that I am adding gmail support to my app, I want to understand why I need to add gmail to this type array, so it becomes:

```
  "types": [
    "jest",
    "gapi",
    "gapi.auth2",
    "gapi.client.docs",
    "gapi.client.gmail"
  ],
```

Without this addition, I get:

`TS2339: Property 'gmail' does not exist on type 'typeof client'.`

Why do I have to add types to the tsconfig array if they types are already declared in package.json as dependencies?

Comment: Did you install the @types associated with this package?

Comment: Yes @LiorPollak the first line of my question says that

Comment: You could just remove `"types"` from tsconfig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your types like that, only the types in the list will be imported, and not all of the available types under your node_modules.

Relevant docs- https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types